# Dygraphs export image createCanvas is not a function

Tags: javascript, dygraphs

I've been trying to implement the exporting of an image of my graphs as per this [example](http://cavorite.com/labs/js/dygraphs-export/) , I kept running into an Dygraph.createCanvas is not a function error.

Downloaded a local copy of the previous link and had it working fine, then tried changing the link to the Dygraphs library from

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://dygraphs.com/dygraph-dev.js"></script>
```

to

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://dygraphs.com/2.0.0/dygraph.js"></script>
```

as used in my application, and this then throws the Dygraph.createCanvas is not a function again.

What am I missing, the function seems to exist in the library, why can't the code see it?

Comment: Could you give us a jsfiddle to try to help you better? Regards!

Comment: @LucidioVacas I can't as the resources aren't https , if I load a javascript console on the top link I can get access to Dygraph.createCanvas, it's not there on the second link. I wonder if that function is now private so the export code can't work on Dygraphs 2.0 ?

Answer (score 2):

I've hit this same problem. I created a jsfiddle for it:
https://jsfiddle.net/n3kozcu1/1/

```
 function export_chart() {
        var img = document.getElementById('demoimg')
        Dygraph.Export.asPNG(g, img);
 }

$("#button").click(export_chart);
```

The fiddle looks a little weird because dygraph-export doesn't appear to be on a CDN anywhere, so I had to just paste it all in. But, I linked to upstream for it so you can see I'm not using an old version.

Super easy contrived example, same the demo site. It doesn't work. Fails with:

"Uncaught TypeError: Dygraph.createCanvas is not a function"

EDIT:
So, looking at the dygraph-utils code:
https://github.com/danvk/dygraphs/blob/aaec6de56dba8ed712fd7b9d949de47b46a76ccd/src/dygraph-utils.js

Dygraphs.createCanvas is just a one liner that creates a canvas. So, I changed the relavent line in dygraphs-export to:

```
canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
```

And it worked, but it bombed out on the next line which calls Dygraph.update. So, I found that and patched it into Dygraph.Export

```
Dygraph.Export.hack_update =  function(self, o) {
  if (typeof(o) != 'undefined' && o !== null) {
    for (var k in o) {
      if (o.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
        self[k] = o[k];
      }
    }
  }
  return self;
};


Dygraph.Export.asCanvas = function (dygraph, userOptions) {
    "use strict";
    var options = {}, 
    canvas = document.createElement('canvas');

    Dygraph.Export.hack_update(options, Dygraph.Export.DEFAULT_ATTRS);
    Dygraph.Export.hack_update(options, userOptions);

    canvas.width = dygraph.width_;
    canvas.height = dygraph.height_ + options.legendHeight;

    Dygraph.Export.drawPlot(canvas, dygraph, options);    
    Dygraph.Export.drawLegend(canvas, dygraph, options);

    return canvas;
};
```

And that "works." I say "works" with the quotes because it still has problems, such as printing axis labels correctly and it doesn't work with HiDPI displays, but it at least doesn't crash.

Comment: Thanks for this, will check it out